# getFeatureInfo is working only if line of polygon is clicked, does not work inside polygon

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have issue with getFeatureInfo function. I can get features of polygon only if it is clicked on line (border) of polygon. By clicking on line, i get features of few polygons, and i want to click inside of polygon and get feature info of that polygon, nothing else.
I'm using Openlayers 2.13 and GeoServer. Where can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are running GeoServer 2.5 and you have faced a bug that happened if there was no fill defined for polygons. Bug was resolved in GeoServer 2.5.2. Read more details from http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/WMS-GetFeatureInfo-with-Polygon-td5163455.html.

First aid would be to add fill to the polygon style. Updating GeoServer should be a definitive fix but if you already run GeoServer 2.6 or 2.7 then it could mean that the bug has popped up again.

Comment: Same problem with GeoServer 2.11.1, solution was filling the Polygon.. # before hex code was the issue

Comment: when you say about fill the polygon, we will do it using openlayer or on the geoserver ?

Comment: On GeoServer. The old buggy version thought that if polygon was not filled the was no feature to ask information from.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed problem by filling polygons with some color. Note: I'm running GeoServer 2.5.2 and bug is not fixed. But link above is very usefull, it helped me. Thanks to user30184.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <sld:Fill>
          <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#F6F4DB</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.20</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Fill>
```

Add value of fill-opacity 0.20 something like that